# Page creation dynamically codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I was working with a team recently for new website of a school & successfully completed. We had given him the admin panel where ever he want he can edit the pages or add images as he want & I used the tinymce editor.
Now the client needs a new page but he wants to create a new page when ever needed is that is possible I don't know how to create that code because I am a new to php we used codeigniter 3.0.
Because when he clicks on a single button it must create a controller and model and view for that page and a new table in database. 
Can any one help me out...

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused with what your client wants.

Your client wants a static CMS page (managed from admin panel).

So, Controller, Model and View are not mandatory.

Create a database table if you don't have `pages`.

And save page content, page title, meta and other stuff there.

Create a controller (for one time) named `page` or whatever you choose,

Create a function there, and show page from database.

eg. http://yoursite.com/page/show/aboutus

Now, it will call `show()` method from `page` controller and `aboutus` is an argument.

Fetch data from `pages` table with `aboutus` and show it.

You can rewrite routes with `routes.php` to make URLs look beautiful.